# SQL запрос для двух подчинённых таблиц

Tags: sql-server, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать запрос для следующей ситуации:
[image]

Случай когда в серверной отдельный шкаф для коммутаторов и отдельный для патч-панелей. 
Когда схема была линейна и было условие, что всё находится в одном шкафу, я просто делал через `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT   boxs.box, switchs.switch, path_panels.path_panel
FROM  info
LEFT path_panels ON info.id_patch_panels = path_panels.id_patch_panels
LEFT JOIN switchs ON info.id_switchs = switchs.id_switchs
LEFT JOIN boxs ON info.id_boxs = boxs.id_boxs
```

Теперь я добавил в `info` столбец `id_boxs2` и не знаю как получить на выходе, в гриде, столбцы в последовательности: `Шкаф, Коммут., Шкаф2, Патч-панель`. Так же линейно сделать не получается.

Comment: А id_box2 с чем будет связываться и для чего это поле?

Comment: С boxs.id_box, это поле для того чтобы обратится второй раз к списку шкафов и получить Шкаф2 для патч-панелей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может я чего не допонял поправьте если что, но тогда нужно использовать псевдонимы чтоб обратится второй раз к таблице boxs

```
SELECT   b1.box, switchs.switch, b2.box, path_panels.path_panel
FROM  info
LEFT path_panels ON info.id_patch_panels = path_panels.id_patch_panels
LEFT JOIN switchs ON info.id_switchs = switchs.id_switchs
LEFT JOIN boxs b1 ON info.id_boxs = b1.id_boxs
LEFT JOIN boxs b2 ON info.id_boxs2 = b2.id_boxs
```

Comment: Точно, как я не подумал. Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 1):

по хорошему - базу надо перепроектировать

```
SELECT   b.box, b2.box, s.switch, p.path_panel 
FROM  info i
LEFT OUTER JOIN path_panels p ON p.id_patch_panels = i.id_patch_panels
LEFT OUTER JOIN switchs s ON s.id_switchs = i.id_switchs
LEFT OUTER JOIN boxs b ON b.id_boxs = i.id_boxs
LEFT OUTER JOIN boxs b2 ON n2.id_boxs = i.id_boxs2
```